# Turn off typeahead autocomplete temporarily

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I am using [bloodhound](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md) to suggest products from a list. Once selected, input fields will automatically be filled in for the user.

When a user has selected a product, the autocomplete suggestions must be disabled temporarily - *but the input must still be changeable*. If a user presses a button to deselect the product, all input fields will be cleared and the suggestion engine must be enabled again.

I am trying to create two functions: `enableSuggestions()` and `disableSuggestions()`. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you consulted [the documentation](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md)? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you disable the `input` that `typeahead` works on, the suggestions will be disabled as well.

You can disable the input when a suggestion is selected (`typeahead` will trigger an event - `typeahead:select`) and remove the `disabled` attribute when the user deselects the product.